# Get a docker image via command line (for running assembly language on a Mac)

Tags: docker, assembly

I have a book called "Learn to Program with Assembly" by Johnathan Bartlett. The book told me that once I downloaded Docker and had it running, I could get an image created by the author for Mac users to be able to use the code from the book (mostly linux I think) by typing the following into the terminal/command prompt --

```
docker run -it --rm --mount "type=bind,src=`pwd`,target=/my-code" johnnyb61820/linux-assembly
```

I tried this many times, but I am getting an error message --

```
invalid argument ""type=bind,src=/users/hill/dockerdir,target=/my-code"" for "--mount" flag: unexpected key '"type' in '"type=bind'See 'docker run --help'.
```

I really dont know enough about this topic to troubleshoot myself, and I am finding it hard to get help from already existing forum posts or tutorials.
Once I get the image, and am able to get files converted into object files and linked, I can start writing assembly language programs and learn along with this book. I appreciate any help I can get with getting over this hump.

Sorry to anyone who helped me with my last post. It was kind of a waste of time because I didnt include this step.

Comment: Did you copy this from somewhere? Those fancy quotes (`“`) need to be plain old doublequotes `"`.

Comment: there we go, I edited those parsts

Comment: In any case that just lets you mount your current working directory inside the image, you can write your code without that if you edit it inside the vm (assuming it has some editor). However it looks like there is nothing wrong with your command according to [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)

Comment: well docker doesn't have a vm.  this image was specifically made for Mac users who are reading this guide book to be able to practice the mostly linux based code verbatim from the examples of the book. im on a Mac, so these codes won't translate in the command prompt/terminal.

Comment: You can try using the alternate syntax instead of the `mount`, e.g. `-v \`pwd\`:/my-code`

Comment: Please copy-paste the __exact__ terminal output including the input line. This command line _can not_ produce this output.

Comment: awesome. it downloaded!